# Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, forms, object, dispose

My program has multiple forms. The fifth and final form has a button that when clicked closes the application using the method Application.Exit(). However every time I click the button I receive the error 'cannot access a disposed object' surrounding this code on my first form:

```
 frm2 f2 = new frm2();
            this.Hide();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();
```

The compiler indicates that the statement `this.show()` is the problem. Could someone explain why I am receiving this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Is it the line `this.Hide();` that the exception is being thrown on? It could be that the form you show the final form from (`this`) has already been disposed. There seems to be a lot of code missing from this example so it makes it hard to diagnose the exact problem.

Comment: Which line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: I'm with T.S. - you have three separate form variables in play over four lines of code?

Comment: My bad, it should have been f2.ShowDialog(). Anyway the line returning the error is this.show();

Comment: Are you using `Application.DoEvents` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Ah, so when f2 is shown, and you click the close button, it then calls `Application.Exit()`? It's likely that your main form has been disposed by the time `f2.ShowDialog();` returns, then. Why not instead check the DialogResult from ShowDialog, and call Application.Exit in your main form?

Comment: @dcreight no I'm not using Application.DoEvents.

Comment: @dash I have 5 forms, that i go through in order. form1 is opened first and form 5 is opened last. It is at form 5 that I use the Application.Exit() method.

Answer (score 2):

Ok edited my answer, I reproduced your issue.  If you want to use `Form.ShowDialog` then you should set the DialogResult of the control that is closing the application.  So in the buttons properties you should set the dialog result to something, for example `Cancel`.

Then on the buttons click event you would do something like this:

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Otherwise if you don't need to use `Form.ShowDialog`, you can just show Form2.  The above does not produce the error in my testing.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't need to call `Hide` on a form you just created, and you don't need to call `Show` in order to make the model dialog appear. These two calls are not needed here.

Comment: It would be better to just close the form when you want the application to terminate cleanly. If your main message loop was started using `Application.Run(form1)` on this form, the application will exit cleanly. If it isn't, then from the Main, I would attach a handler for the form's `Closed` event that would call `Application.Exit`. The point is - forms shouldn't be the ones to call Exit.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, did `frm2` make a call to `Application.Exit`? If it did, then why are you trying to call `this.Show` again?

Anyway, you may have a problem related to how you started the application's message loop. Are you running `Application.Run()`, or `Application.Run(form1)`?

If you provided a form to `Application.Run()` when you started your message loop, then you should not be calling `Application.Exit` in order to exit the application. Instead, you should simply close your main window, that would cause the message loop to finish, the call to `Application.Run` to return, and your application will terminate cleanly.

Comment: The call to Application.Exit() is made on from my fifth and final form.